# Html.HiddenFor handles string and int differently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My model:

```
    public class VerifyModel
    {
        public string PIN { get; set; }
        public int Attempts { get; set; }
    }
```

My view:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PIN)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Attempts)
```

On entry into the view, I inspect `Model.PIN` and `Model.Attempts` and they contain the correct values passed from the controller, where `Attempts` is non-zero.  The Html rendered is however:

```
<input id="PIN" name="PIN" type="hidden" value="xxxx" />
<input data-val="true" value="0"  data-val-number="The field Attempts must be a number." data-val-required="The Attempts field is required." id="Attempts" name="Attempts" type="hidden"/>
```

The value of Attempts is always 0!  And I did not specify anywhere that the `Attempts` field is mandatory.

How do I solve the problem of int properties in the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you're having problems with `Attempts` not incrementing after the form is posted back with an incorrect `PIN`.  If that assumption is correct then you're experiencing this problem because of the way ModelState works.

The short answer to the problem is simply to call [ModelState.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.remove%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) from your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(VerifyModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Attempts");  
    model.Attempts++;  

    return View(model);
}
```

If you'd like a full explanation of why this is the case, see [ASP.NET MVC’s Html Helpers Render the Wrong Value!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx).  Excerpt:

> ### Why?
>
> ASP.NET MVC assumes that if you’re rendering a View in response to an HTTP POST, and you’re using the Html Helpers, then you are most likely to be redisplaying a form that has failed validation. Therefore, the Html Helpers actually check in ModelState for the value to display in a field before they look in the Model. This enables them to redisplay erroneous data that was entered by the user, and a matching error message if needed.

Comment: Brilliant!  StackOverflow needs more responders like you, who figure out what the OP is trying to achieve. http://all-things-pure.blogspot.sg/2011/08/expert-is.html